# Is it good to start a website with keyword very popular or not so popular?

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search-console, keywords

I am planning to launch a website. However, it is still undecided as there are many keywords on google, to begin with.

My question is whether it is good to be a part of a well-established keyword with millions of search results already, or would it be good to be part of a keyword which has less than 100 search results or none.

Comment: Stop thinking about keywords and just create well-written content. Keywords will come naturally.

Answer (score 1):

> I am planning to launch a website.

Okay. What goal are you attempting to meet by having this website?

Generally, keyword selection comes *after* you've decided what you're selling, which topic you're blogging about, et cetera.

When it does come time to pick your keywords, you'll want to pick the keywords which are most specific to what your site is about (there's no sense trying to optimize for the word "food" if your site is about "canned lutefisk", for example) and, amongst the terms which match what you offer, you'll want to pick the terms which get the most traffic (and, if you're selling something, the terms which result in the most purchases).

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I predict, you are planning to open a blog. A blog has many posts. And every post can many keywords.

If you write a post over well-established keyword then, of course, it'll show that your site contents are up to date. And it may bring your site upward in latest news or blog search.

If you write about the topics which are less popular then it might impact that you are having some unique posts. And ultimately it'll increase the traffic on your site.

So I suggest you that you open a blog. And go for both.